# NSDictionaryController doesn't seem to observe changes to content dictionary

Tags: cocoa, nsdictionary, cocoa-bindings, nstableview

I must be missing something simple, but I am having some trouble binding a tableView to an NSDictionaryController. Here is a model of my current scheme:

TableViewColumn --bindsTo-->DictionaryController.arrangedObjects.(value or key)
                --bindsTo-->someClass.someClassMember.aDictionary.

I've tested the tableView by adding an entry to aDictionary on init, which is displayed correctly. But when another method produces an object that is then added to aDictionary, the TableView doesn't seem to update or even know that aDictionary now has two entries. I've tried everything I can think of. I am *not* directly accessing aDictionary....I've tried (in someClassMember) [self aDictionary setValue:forKey:], and [self setValue:forKeyPath:@"aDictionary"] and similar variations. The key is a string, so it should be KVC/KVO compliant, and I have '@synthesize'd aDictionary in someClassMember.

What am I missing? Why won't new entries to the dictionary show up in the tableView?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wish someone answered to the question asked in the comments for the first answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `[self willChangeValueForKey:@"aDictionary"];` before adding the new item, and `[self didChangeValueForKey:@"aDictionary"];` afterwards in `someClass`

Comment: This helped, in that it revealed a problem that one of the objects in aDictionary did not implement 'copyWithZone' properly. But even after correcting that, I still need [self will/didChangeValueForKey]. I guess I don't understand KVC enough. What about my design keeps the dictionaryController or tableView from observing a dictionary whose contents are changed programatically? I should be KVC compliant, why do I need to manually notify?

Comment: Can someone answer to the above question?

Comment: As I understand it you are observing the mutable dictionary object. As it is currently implemented it does not post key value observing notifications when it is mutated. You are doing nothing wrong it is just not posting notifications. So if you want everyone to know when the dictionary is mutated you will have to post the notifications yourself. If you don't think that is the correct behavior file a bug report with Apple.