# Add objects to NSDictionaryController

Tags: macos, controller, nsdictionary, cocoa-bindings, nstableview

I have an NSTableView which is bound to an NSDictionaryController.  I have set this and the content dictionary through the interface builder.  The question I have is, how do I add objects to the dictionary in a manner that the controller will see it automatically and display it in the table.

I've seen in examples about NSArrayController that you add the new objects through the controller rather than the actual array so the controller sees the change.  However, I don't see a similar way of doing this with the dictionarycontroller...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I ended up figuring this out.  I figured since the arraycontroller mirrored the use of an array that a dictionarycontroller would do the same but it is not so.  The process is a little bit different...

So if you have a dictionarycontroller that you would like to add values to so it can update anything binding to it you use the following process:

```
//Creates and returns a new key-value pair to represent an entry in the 
//content dictionary.
id newObject = [dictController newObject];
//Use NSDictionaryControllerKeyValuePair Protocol setKey 
[newObject setKey:@"Key"];
//Use NSDictionaryControllerKeyValuePair Protocol setValue
[newObject setValue:@"value"];
//Add the object to the controller
[dictController addObject:newObject];
```

This will in effect, update both the dictionarycontroller and add the value to the content dictionary.  You cannot use setValue:ForKey in this case because this is not a method implemented in the NSDictionaryControllerKeyValuePair Protocol.

I hope this can help others using these controllers!

Comment: This worked for me, but then I found this question which seemed more aligned with what I wanted to do  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596229/nsdictionarycontroller-doesnt-seem-to-observe-changes-to-content-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

jasons answer didn't work for me because in my implementation it ran into an error on the line [newObject setValue:@"value"], saying that multiple methods were found with mismatched results and i couldn't find any other method that would add the new entry as intended.

after a lot of searching and trying i came up with this solution:
just renew the binding everytime the dictController needs to be updated, like this:

```
[dictController bind:NSContentDictionaryBinding toObject:self withKeyPath:@"nameOfMyDictionary" options:nil];
```

so throughout my code i add items to my dictionary, and just before showing the table with the contents of my dictionary i reset the binding. this is probably a dirty solution, but it worked for me.

Comment: As I understand this issue the problem is that NSMutableDictionary does not post a key value observing notification for itself. It will happily say key "whatever" has changed, but it does not say hey "I have been changed". This means that the bound object cannot update itself because it does not receive notifications for any mutations for the dictionary. So all you are really doing with this assigning to content every time it updates. You could also call willChangeValueForKey: didChangeValueForKey: before and after editing the content dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent! modified for Swift3:

```
    // Use NSDictionaryControllerKeyValuePair Protocol setKey
    let temp = myDictionaryController.newObject()
    temp.setValue(name, forKey: "key")
    temp.setValue(list, forKey: "value")
    myDictionaryController.addObject(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jason's answer can be simplified:

```
        NSDictionaryControllerKeyValuePair *c = myDictionaryController.newObject;
        c.key   = @"foo";
        c.value = @"bar";
        [myDictionaryController addObject:c];
```